# Android ndk build failed

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build, ijkplayer

Though my current ndk version is greater than r10e , but it is saying

```
build on Linux x86_64
ANDROID_NDK=/root/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/
IJK_NDK_REL=15.1.4119039
You need the NDKr10e or later
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to build [ijkplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer) , I am just following the build instruction when I tried to execute the `./compile-ffmpeg.sh all` I got this error.

Comment: And where does the _"You need the NDKr10e or later"_ log come from?

Comment: @Michael from terminal after executing `./compile-ffmpeg.sh all` this command

Comment: Yeah, but from where does it originate

Comment: @Michael I have edited my question

Answer (score 3):

This library has hardcoded dependency on NDK release; the latest commit for 
[android/contrib/tools/do-detect-env.sh](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer/blob/067317a4ce4fd7f02e138ce718e60faf9cbd7c3f/android/contrib/tools/do-detect-env.sh) adds detection of NDK r.14. You have the latest r.15c installed. I would recommend to download r.14 from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html instead of tuning the build scripts: the new release has some [*breaking changes*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r15-release/CHANGELOG.md). They come with significant enhancements, but you will not gain much for a project that has already been  tested on r.14.